# DELETE FROM combobox.text database

Tags: c#, sql

I get :

> SYNTAX ERROR IN FROM Clause;

`cmdbox_Model.Text` is displaying the name of the table.

Here is the code

I want to select the table name directly from the combo-box. So went the user select a model type it be directly deleted from that table.

```
    string Product = cmdbox_Product1.Text;
    string Model = cmdbox_Model.Text;
    string MacID = txt_MAC_id.Text;

    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open && (cmdbox_Product1.Text == "MODEM" && cmdbox_Model.Text == Model))
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM " + cmdbox_Model.Text + "WHERE MacID = @MacID", conn);

        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MacID", MacID);

        try
        {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure you Want to Delete this \""+ cmdbox_Product1.Text + "\"?", "Confirm DELETE",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    MessageBox.Show("Successful Deleted", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                }

                else MessageBox.Show("Failed To Delete", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1); }

                conn.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException expe)
        {
                MessageBox.Show(expe.Message);
                MessageBox.Show("Error Failed to delete", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Add a space before `WHERE MacID=@MacID"`

Comment: 1. Add a space before your `where` clause. 2. Use parameters so you dont have SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: What is the name of the modem model? Does it contains spaces?

Comment: the name is SB610. No it doesn't contain any space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the space between table name and WHERE.

Try This:

```
OleDbCommand cmd3 = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM " + cmdbox_Model.Text + " WHERE MacID=@MacID", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you include the table name in the query?

```
"DELETE FROM " + cmdbox_Model.Text + "WHERE MacID=@MacID"
```

You haven't mentioned the Table name.

This

```sql
DELETE 
FROM TABLE NAME
WHERE
```

is how you write the query.